# How to open external URL in default browser and all internal links in WebView Android?

Tags: android, webview, android-browser, external-links, internal-link

I am using `WebView` in my page and using local file `assets` to displaying in `WebView` but in main HTML page external website (not local) and I want to open just that link in default Browser on the users device 
[image: this picture disciple situation]

This is my code in 'onCreate' method

```
WebView v;

v=(WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
v.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
WebViewClient vc= new WebViewClient();
v.setWebViewClient(vc);
v.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/home.html");
```

When I run the application the internal link is working good but the external link "www.apple.com" en in the web view

I searched the same question and found this solution but still external link opens in WebView

```
WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
String url = "file:///android_asset/home.html";
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

and class

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains("http")){ // Could be cleverer and use a regex
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url); // Leave webview and use browser
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url); // Stay within this webview and load url
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
  if (url.contains("http")) { // Could be cleverer and use a regex
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url); // Leave webview and use browser
  } else {
    view.loadUrl(url); // Stay within this webview and load url
    return true;
  }
```

to

```
 if (url.contains("http")) { // Could be cleverer and use a regex
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
    return true;
 }
 return false;
```

Note : replace `mContext` with your activity context.

Comment: @Milaaaad Happy to help,enjoy.